# How do I execute a method in my view controller every x milliseconds?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How do I execute a method in my view controller every x milliseconds?

Answer (score 7):

Create a timer that takes your view and function as arguments to be called. Alternatively you can use NSInvocation with NSTimer.

E.g.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:myView selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```